# Can there be multiple rendering worker threads

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3

I've recently come across the `Worker & WorkerDomain` classes available to AS3, however there doesn't seem any mention of how each thread interacts with whats being rendered on screen.

> Is there a way to render to the screen on one thread, then after an
>   event switch rendering to the other thread?

My initial assumption is threads **apart** from the *"Primordial"* thread should only be used for background processing, but I'm hoping that may not be the case.

Comment: workers are meant to execute code not to display anything on screen.

Comment: The rendering operations are part of the main thread Flash uses, so you cannot switch or duplicate it. You can only delegate code to workers which will work just until the rendering part begins. Unfortunately, the short answer is no :)